mounting NFS times out on Debian linux
I have two Linux (Debian) machines:

server at 192.168.10.11
client at 192.168.10.10

On one of them, I installed the NFS server and set it up following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-debian-11 and https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-nfs-server-and-client-on-debian. Basically what I did was, on the server:

install nfs-kernel-server
NEED_STATD="no" and NEED_IDMAPD="yes" in /etc/default/nfs-common
RPCNFSDOPTS="-N 2 -N 3" and RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids -N 2 -N 3" in /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server" RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids -N 2 -N 3"
added /data as export to /etc/exports

I am not running UFW or any FW on either machines.
On the client machine, when I try to connect, it times out.
$ sudo mount.nfs4 -v 192.169.10.11:/data /data
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Sat Oct 19 16:37:27 2024
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.169.10.11,clientaddr=192.168.10.10'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs4: Connection timed out

Output of my NFS configuration:
$ sudo cat /etc/exports
/data 192.168.10.10 (rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

$ sudo cat /etc/default/nfs-common
NEED_STATD="no"
STATDOPTS=
NEED_IDMAPD="yes"
NEED_GSSD=

$ sudo cat /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server
RPCNFSDCOUNT=8
RPCNFSDPRIORITY=0
RPCNFSDOPTS="-N 2 -N 3"
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids -N 2 -N 3"
NEED_SVCGSSD=""
RPCSVCGSSDOPTS=""


Add the output of the client and server logs while mounting to the question.

Just an idea. Should both computer be connected via WLAN, check the config of your WLAN-router, some WLAN-router disallow direct network connections between WLAN clients. This can be enabled.

I am closing this question cause I am an idiot. I was using the wrong IP in the client command. I'm so sorry!
